# Problema ao importar função em React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Oi, estou fazendo um app em react native usando expo e estou tendo o seguinte error;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já tentei de tudo, até aonde eu entendo ele não está reconhecendo a função `LoginScreen` em;

```
  <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
```

o estranho que quando coloco a função e os styles dentro da App.js ele funciona normalmente, então acredito que seja algo relacionado ao import, mas não consegui resolver isso. Segue abaixo código.

```
App.js

import LoginScreen from './src/screens/login/login';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}>
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
-----------------------------------------------------
Login.js

import {View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {styles} from "./styles";
import {AppLoading} from 'expo';
import {useFonts} from 'expo-font';

export default function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts(
        {'Monoton': require('../../../assets/fonts/Monoton-Regular.ttf'), 'RobotoSlab': require('../../../assets/fonts/RobotoSlab.ttf')}
    );
    if (!fontsLoaded) {
        return <AppLoading/>;
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logobox}>
                    <View style={styles.logo}>
                        <Text style={styles.tituloText}>
                            iFarm
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.subtituloText}>
                            AGRICULTOR
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.login}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="E-mail"
                        placeholderTextColor="#787878"
                        style={styles.input}/>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Senha"
                        placeholderTextColor="#787878"
                        style={styles.input}/>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => {}}
                        style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>ENTRAR</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <View style={styles.opcoes}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
                            <Text style={styles.esqueci}>Esqueci a senha</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
                            <Text style={styles.criar}>Criar nova conta</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.montanhas}>
                    <View style={styles.montanha_1}/>
                    <View style={styles.montanha_3}/>
                    <View style={styles.sol}/>
                    <View style={styles.montanha_2}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Se estiver usando o VS Code e passar o cursor do mouse por cima do caminho do import (./src/screens/login/login) ele exibe o caminho completo, se não exibir o import está com o caminho errado. Não dá pra afirmar pois você não colocou a estrutura das pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim, verifiquei aqui o caminho está correto Rafael, fiz usando o auto complete do vscode, porém de qualquer forma ele não reconhece a função "LoginScreen" do arquivo "login.js".